# Expression sur visage d'un personnage

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

In English I could say "she had a sad expression (on her face)". Can I say "elle a eu une expression malheureuse sur son visage"?

Comment: 1- sad → *triste* (*malheureux*  → unfortunate).  2- *Elle avait l'air triste* (literally it means she looked sad), *son visage reflétait la tristesse*, more literal :  *l'expression de son visage était triste*

Comment: @Laure: can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 3):

It's typically the sort of thing you can't translate literally. You will probably get several proposals that can all be good.

As far as I'm concerned I find that French focuses more on the part of the body (here the face) and the person themselves stays behind the face. This implies the use of a different verb, not *avoir*

> *Son visage reflétait/exprimait la tristesse.*
>
> *L'expression de son visage reflétait la tristesse.*

In those sentences I've used a noun (*tristesse*) in place of an adjective (*triste*). You could still use an adjective with:

> *Son visage (l'expression sur son visage) était triste*.

If you still want to keep the person up front I suggest something like:

> *Elle avait l'air triste.*
> Which is the literal translation for  "She looked sad".

Complementary remarks:
1- "Sad" is *triste* in French. *Malheureux* means either
"unfortunate" when used for things or "miserable" when used for people.

2- Without further context of a chain of events we would not use the *passé composé* but the *imparfait* in that sentence. It is a mere description of an uncompleted action/state.